# Error with finding nth number of Fibonacci using recursion

Tags: java, scope, fibonacci

I am having trouble with an error saying that my int variable final may not have been initialized however I thought I initialized it in the `if` statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibo
{
   static int fibNum(int num)
   {
      int finish;
      if(num < 0)
      {   
         finish = -1;
      }
      else if(num == 0 || num == 1)
      {
         finish = num;
      }   
      else if(num > 1)
      {
         finish = fibNum(num-1) + fibNum(num-2);
      }
      return finish;
   }//end fibNum

   public static void main(String []args) 
   {
    int num;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = in.nextInt();
    fibNum(num);
    System.out.println(" is the nth number in the fibbonaci sequence that you are looking for");
   }//end main
}//end class
```

Error:

```
Fibo.java:20: error: variable finish might not have been initialized
      return finish;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the member fields (variables) can be initialized to default values implicitly, the local variables cannot, so you should initialize it explicitly by changing this:

```
int finish;
```

to this:

```
int finish = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the variable.

Change:

```
int finish;
```

To

```
 int finish = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Must Declare Return Variable. Because if condition can execute only when calling a method.

```
int finish = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Local variables do not get default values. Their initial values are undefined without assignment by some means. Before you can use local variables they must be initialized.

That's why you have to intialize the local variable.

```
int finish = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I understand it a lot better now!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must initialize the int variable **finish** in fibNum method